# How to debug code in R for getting standard deviation of variable by group with Dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the package "nycflights13", I'm taking on a beginner's tidyverse question. I want to get the standard deviation of arrival delay (arr_delay) by carrier. Really have no idea why my code isn't working. It produces the summarize table with two columns: carrier and my new variable sd_arr_delay, but all the values for sd_arr_delay are NA.

I already checked the table before the summarize, so the filter and the group_by functions appear to be working.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights_2c <- flights %>% 
   filter(origin == "JFK" & dest == "BOS") %>%
   group_by(carrier) %>% 
   summarise(sd_arr = sd(as.numeric(arr_delay)))
```

No error message, just a column filled with NA's.

Comment: Probably need to use `na.rm = TRUE` inside of `sd()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
flights_2c <- flights %>% 
   filter(origin == "JFK" & dest == "BOS") %>%
   group_by(carrier) %>% 
   summarise(sd_arr = sd(as.numeric(arr_delay),na.rm = TRUE))
```

There are `NA` values in the `arr_delay` column which means that all the `sd` calculations will end up returning `NA` unless you tell `sd` to remove them when doing the calculation.

Be on the lookout for `na.rm` arguments in lots of R commands, like `mean`, `median`, etc. If there are possibly `NA` values in your input, you'll likely want to use that argument.